# Start Outlook Command Line Switches

Tags: c#, outlook

I have the following code:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key =
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\microsoft\\windows\\
currentversion\\app paths\\OUTLOOK.EXE");

string path = (string)key.GetValue("Path");

if( path != null)
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("OUTLOOK.EXE");
else
 MessageBox.Show("There is no Outlook in this computer!", "SystemError",       

MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

The code works fine, but I want to start the outlook in differents way, using command line switches like: Safe, cleanreminders, cleanrules.

Any thought?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what is the problem? It looks like you have some very clear ideas about what you want to do!

Comment: It is hard to believe that `Process.Start` does not accept command line arguments... Did you check documentation while asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

An example I found at http://www.dotnetperls.com/process

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
startInfo.Arguments = file;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Arguments:
Stores the arguments, such as -flags or filename. This is a string property.